# OpenCV Video Capture in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-capture

I'm new to opencv, and I saw a tutorial demonstrating how to use the cam on computers to imshow constant video frames.

Here's the code:

```
int main(int argv, char** argc) {
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture vid(0);   

    if (!vid.isOpened()) { 
        return -1;
    }


    while (vid.read(frame)) {

        imshow("cam", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0; }
```

So what I can't understand is that isn't waitKey(30) will terminate the while loop in the first iteration when it waits > 30ms? Meaning only 1 frame will be shown in imshow and nothing more?

I tested it with a modification which replaces 'break' with nothing in the 'if', and then the code can show constant video frames with no issue.

```
        while (vid.read(frame)) {

        imshow("cam", frame);
          if (waitKey(30) >= 0) {
                //do nothing
          }     
        }
```

The provided code from a tutorial that I have the question with, the provider can run it with no problem. Use that code, I can only load 1 frame and then stop, and that's how I expect the code to do as well.

I don't know if I misunderstood the code or what, it should be only showing 1 frame and stop, but others can run the code and show multiple frames.

Comment: can you try int key = waitKey(30); if (key>=0) std::cout << "pressed key " << key << std::endl; and tell us what kind of value is printed there?

Comment: Are you sure you're not pressing any key? Maybe one of your keyboard keys is stuck. waitKey returns -1 if no key is pressed in that period.

Comment: @Micka you're a genius, it says pressed key 255 multiple times. So what does that indicate?

Comment: I understand now, so waitKey() is expected to return -1, but mine is 255. So simply change the if statement to if (waitKey(30) <= 0) {break;} will do the job. Thank you @Micka.

Comment: This is a known bug. It should be fixed in any recent release.

Comment: As a workaround, use `waitKey(30) != 255` or you won't be able to quit the loop by pressing any key